# 400 bad request admin-ajax file upload

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax

I'm having some trouble while I'm making an upload plugin. I'm using ajax to do the upload, but during the first test I get a 400 bad request error. 
Is there a fix for this?

Here is the js code

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#process-upload').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', $('#imageFile').prop('files')[0] );
      data.append('action', 'new_message');
      data.append('message', $('#imageMessage').val());

      $.ajax({
        url: wpu.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          window.alert('Done!');
        }
      });

    });

  });
}(jQuery));
```

and this is the php:

```
public function __construct()
  {
    add_shortcode( 'upload-form', array($this, 'upload_form') );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'main') );
    add_action( 'admin_ajax_new_message', array($this, 'process_upload') );
    add_action( 'admin_ajax_nopriv_new_message', array($this, 'process_upload') );
  }

  public function main()
  {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-upload', plugins_url( 'ajax-upload.min.js' , __FILE__), array('jquery'), null );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-upload', 'wpu', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
      )
    );

  }

  public function upload_form( $attr, $content = null )
  {
    ob_start();
    ?>
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="imageFile" accept="image/*">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="imageFile">Choose file</label>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="imageMessage" name="message"></textarea>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="process-upload"><?php _e('Save'); ?></button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="cancel-upload"><?php _e('Cancel'); ?></button>
      </form>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
  }

  public function process_upload()
  {
    $file = array(
      'name' => $_FILES['imageFile']['name'],
      'type' => $_FILES['imagefile']['type'],
      'tmp_name' => $_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'],
      'size' => $_FILES['imageFile']['size'],
      'error' => $_FILES['imageFile']['error'],
    );

    $upload = wp_handle_upload( $file , array( 'test_form' => false ) );

    var_dump($upload);

  }
```

Comment: the hooks starts with `wp_ajax_...` and not `admin_ajax_...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action should be `wp_ajax` and `wp_ajax_nopriv` instead of `admin_ajax`.

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_new_message', array($this, 'process_upload') );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_new_message',array($this, 'process_upload') );
```

Comment: Thanks, It was a mistake I made due this is my first time that I use ajax with wordpress